# when to return a function's value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have been learning react js recently and there is this code, where my tutor uses this code to reset values in state...

```
  handleDelete = counterId => {
    const tempCounter = this.state.counters.filter(c => c.id !== counterId);
    this.setState({ counters: tempCounter });
  };

  reset = () => {
    const resetCounters = this.state.counters.map(c => {
      c.value = 0;
      return c;
    });
    this.setState({ counters: resetCounters });
  };
```

here in 'handleDelete' function my tutor didn't return value in 'tempCounter' variable, but in 'reset' function tutor returns the value of 'c', why ?

Answer (score 3):

The arrow function inside the `this.state.counter.filter()` returns the boolean value of the expression `c.id !== counterId`.
When you don't put the brackets "{}" after declaring an arrow function, it means what comes after the arrow "=>" is considered the return value of it.

Answer (score 0):

This function:

```
  handleDelete = counterId => {
    const tempCounter = this.state.counters.filter(c => c.id !== counterId); // implicit return 
    this.setState({ counters: tempCounter });
  };
```

OR

```
handleDelete = counterId => {
  const tempCounter = this.state.counters.filter(c => {
    return c.id !== counterId; // explicit return 
  });
  this.setState({ counters: tempCounter });
};
```

More contrived example:

```js
const people = [
  { name: 'Bob', age: 20 },
  { name: 'Jane', age: 30 },
  { name: 'Mike', age: 40 },
  { name: 'Smith', age: 50 },
];

const under35implicit = people.filter(person => person.age < 35)

// same as 

const under35explicit = people.filter(person => {
  return person.age < 35
})

console.log(under35implicit)

console.log(under35explicit)
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

In an arrow function, if there is an expression after the arrow, it will be implicitly returned. If there are curly braces, then an explicit return statement is required to return a value. You could rewrite the first function like:

```
const tempCounter = this.state.counters.filter(c => {
    return c.id !== counterId
});
```

But it is more concise the first way.

The second function could also be reversed to use an explicit return, using spreading:

```
const resetCounters = this.state.counters.map(c => ({ ...c, value: 0 }));
```

We need to wrap the object in parentheses, otherwise it will become a function body contained in curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Look closely! The returned value `c` is not the return value of your function `reset`, but rather the return value of your function `c => { c.value = 0; return c; }`, which you used within `this.state.counters.map` as parameter.

This being clarified both functions `reset` and `handleDelete` don't return any values. They don't even have to, because they are most likely used as event handlers (button clicked, etc.). Therefore they trigger a state change by themselves with `this.setState`.